# How to delete multiple elements if checkbox is checked using javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I got this code, I figured out how to delete one element with the checkbox checked but if I try to delete the second div it won't let me?
Does anyone have a solution to it?

HTML

```
<div id="product-space">
            <div id="product"> <input type="checkbox" id="delete-checkbox">
                <p> JVC200123 <br> Acme DISC <br> 1.00 $ <br> Size: 700 MB</p>
            </div>
            <div id="product"> <input type="checkbox" id="delete-checkbox">
                <p> KRK201929 <br> Acme DISC <br> 1.00 $ <br> Size: 700 MB</p>
            </div>
        </div>
<button type="submit" name="button" value="enter" id="button" onclick="removeCheckedCheckboxes()">MASS DELETE</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function removeCheckedCheckboxes() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("delete-checkbox");
    var box = document.getElementById("product");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        box.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use classname  for mass delete

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code does not work is because you use the `id` attribute multiple times with the same value. This is against HTML standards. Also you use `getElementById` which can only return a single element.

I would suggest using css classes for marking all relevant elements, and using a simple CSS selector for matching all checked boxes.

```js
function removeCheckedCheckboxes() {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-checkbox:checked");
  checked.forEach((elem) => {
    elem.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="product-space">
  <div class="product"> <input type="checkbox" class="delete-checkbox">
    <p> JVC200123 <br> Acme DISC <br> 1.00 $ <br> Size: 700 MB</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product"> <input type="checkbox" class="delete-checkbox">
    <p> KRK201929 <br> Acme DISC <br> 1.00 $ <br> Size: 700 MB</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="button" value="enter" id="deleteButton" onclick="removeCheckedCheckboxes()">MASS DELETE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

see [the ref](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid):

> getElementById will return the **first** element with the given ID

You could name them as different ids if just want to handle this issue quickly.

Answer (score 0):

[`Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is used to find elements from DOM with matching ID. It returns a single Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string. In your case you have multiple elements with same id. So it will always returns the first element while running this script. So your second element remains in visible state always.

So a better approach is to pick the element using class name rather than id, because id is supposed to be unique and class names need not be unique.

**Logic**

- Pick the target elements using the class names. I used same class names `product` for the container div and `delete-checkbox` for the check boxes.
- On clicking delete button, loop through the elements with class name `product`.
- Find checkbox inside each `product` element by checking an element with classname `delete-checkbox` inside each node.
- Check the `checked` status of each checkbox, if checked, hide the box.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".product");
function removeCheckedCheckboxes() {
    boxes.forEach((box) => {
        const checkBox = box.querySelector('.delete-checkbox');
        if (checkBox.checked == true) {
            box.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="product-space">
    <div class="product">
        <input type="checkbox" class="delete-checkbox">
        <p> JVC200123 <br> Acme DISC <br> 1.00 $ <br> Size: 700 MB</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <input type="checkbox" class="delete-checkbox">
        <p> KRK201929 <br> Acme DISC <br> 1.00 $ <br> Size: 700 MB</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit"
    name="button" value="enter" id="button"
    onclick="removeCheckedCheckboxes()">MASS
    DELETE
</button>
```

Comment: Please edit your post to correct spelling if possible.

Comment: @ArnavThorat Fixed

Answer (score 0):

the first thing is, both of your items have the same ID, and you must never use the same ID for multiple divs's. When you use document.getElementById, you return only the first object, and you are not exactly deleting the code by clicking in your button. Try get your element by a class or a tagName like those input fields of yours.

```js
function removeCheckedCheckboxes() {
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    var product = list[i]
    if (product.checked)
      product.parentElement.hidden = true
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="product-space">
  <div class="product">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p> JVC200123 <br> Acme DISC <br> 1.00 $ <br> Size: 700 MB</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p> KRK201929 <br> Acme DISC <br> 1.00 $ <br> Size: 700 MB</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button
  type="submit"
  name="button"
  value="enter"
  id="button"
  onclick="removeCheckedCheckboxes()">
  MASS DELETE
</button>
```

> https://www.quora.com/Is-it-ever-ok-to-use-the-same-ID-for-multiple-elements-in-HTML-Doesnt-CSS-specificity-make-IDs-more-granular-than-classes-Doesnt-this-violate-the-rules-of-HTML-Is-there-ever-a-reason-to-do-this